# How to access the <li> items using Selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, xpath-1.0

I want to access `<li>` items in a webpage.

From the given HTML, how can I access the list items such as User, Make & Model??

I am not able to retrieve the content of the list. My code is not executing the codes added inside the for loop.

HTML:

```
<li class="nav-item"> <span class="nav-link add-items" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#add"> <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> &nbsp; Add</span>
  <ul class="add-menu collapse" id="add">
    <li><span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add-user-modal">User</span></li>
    <li><span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add-make-modal">Make</span></li>
    <li><span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add-model-modal">Model</span></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Post your code in your post

Comment: @Thomas Which language are you using Java / Python / C# / JavaScript?

Comment: if(driver!=null) {
System.out.println("Driver is not null");     
List<WebElement> add= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li/span[text()='Add']"));
for(WebElement element:add) {
    System.out.println("for loop");
      System.out.println(element.getText());
     }            
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"add\"]/li[1]/span")).click();
     Thread.sleep(1000);


Kindly note that I am not able to enter the loop using the above code. Also, the "Add" link is appearing with + sign and options are visible when we click the + symbol. Still, I am not able to click the "Add"

Answer (score 0):

To match a single item you can use the following [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) locator :

```
//li/span[text()='User']
```

[image]

To match all items and get their text the relevant [XPath Expression](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=40044727) would be:

```
//ul[@class='add-menu collapse']/li/span
```

Example [Python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html) code:

```
for li in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='add-menu collapse']/li/span"):
    print(li.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the list items such as **User**, **Make** & **Model** you can use the following solution:

- *Java*:

  - Using `cssSelector`:

    ```
    List<String> myItems = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("li.nav-item ul.add-menu.collapse li>span"))).stream().map(element->element.getAttribute("innerHTML")).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(myItems);
    ```
  - Using `xpath`:

    ```
    List<String> myItems = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//li[@class='nav-item']//ul[@class='add-menu collapse']//li/span"))).stream().map(element->element.getAttribute("innerHTML")).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(myItems);
    ```
- *Python*:

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.nav-item ul.add-menu.collapse li>span")))])
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='nav-item']//ul[@class='add-menu collapse']//li/span")))])
    ```
  - **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

    ```
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    ```